# PowerShell error record has empty/incorrect 'InvocationInfo'

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I am running a PowerShell script in Azure DevOps, and in the event of a command failing I need to log a warning so that observers can see that the script did not run as expected.

As part of the warning, I wish to output the path to the script and the line number / offset where an exception occurred.

To do this, am using the `$_` variable within the `catch` or a try/catch block.

```
$command = "New-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -Name {0} -ResourceGroupName {1} -KeyKind {2}" -f $Name, $ResourceGroupName, $keyKind
Write-Verbose ("##[command] {0}" -f $command)
try {
    Invoke-Expression $command
}
catch
{
    Write-Host ("##[warning] {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message -replace "`r`n", ". ")
    Write-Host ("##vso[task.logissue type=warning;sourcepath={0};linenumber={1};columnnumber={2};]{3}" -f $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName, $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber, $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine, $_.Exception.Message -replace "`r`n", ". ")
}
```

However, for some reason within `$_.InvocationInfo`, the `ScriptName` is blank and both `ScriptLineNumber` and `OffsetInLine` are set to `1`.

If I output `$_.ScriptStackTrace` I see that there are three messages, and presumably `$_` relies on the last message in the stack trace.

```
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\pathTo\My-Script.ps1: line 40
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
```

What I don't understand is where these messages on the stack trace are coming from, and why they don't contain the script name, line number, etc.

Comment: This is due to your use of `Invoke-Expression` and is expected behavior. Why use `Invoke-Expression` in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Ah, OK, that's a shame. Why use - Because I wish to log the command being run in Azure DevOps, so by adding it to a variable I can ensure consistancy of the command that is output and run by `Invoke-Expression`. Is the expected behaviour that you describe documented anywhere, so that I can familiarise myself with it?

Comment: Not sure it's explicitly documented anywhere, but `Invoke-Expression` works by creating a new in-memory scriptblock that then executes separately, and this scriptblock won't have the original scripts invocation information attached (because it's not guaranteed to be part of it). I haven't used pipeline in AzDO for a while, but maybe enabling more verbose logging on the pipeline will give you the full transcript log? Not sure

Comment: Sadly not, if you want anything you have to add it to your script. They do offer a `System.Debug` variable, but setting that to true only runs your scripts with `-Debug` and/or `-Verbose` (can't remember which). No matter, I'll exclude the file/position from my warning - it's a small script so it should be pretty obvious where the issue lies! Thanks.

Comment: I should warn you that using `Invoke-Expression` is generally a really bad idea - because anyone who can influence the input gets arbitrary code execution in your AzDO instance. If someone manages to influence the value of `$resourceGroupName` for example, they could simply set it to `"GroupName; $(Execute-MaliciousCode -PwnDavidsReleaseInfra)`

Comment: Fair point, I'll review my use of that command.

Answer (score 0):

After comments on OP stating that my issue was being caused be the use of `Invoke-Expression`, and suggesting that I don't use that cmdlet, I investigated other possible solutions and I came across the brave new world (for me!) of [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7).

Sadly there is no `Format-Splat` function, so I had to write a little one, but as it'll be used several times in the script I'm not too bothered. Hoepfully this is something MS will add in the future.

Happily, using the snippets below means that warnings are now being written properly for Azure DevOps -

> ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;sourcepath=C:\pathTo\My-Script.ps1;linenumber=60;columnnumber=17;]Something went wrong.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Specialized

function Format-Splat
{
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][OrderedDictionary]$Hashtable)

    $output = @()
    foreach ($key in $Hashtable.Keys)
    {
        $output += "-{0} {1}" -f $key, $Hashtable[$key]
    }    
    Write-Output ($output -join " ")
}

$parameters = [Ordered]@{ Name = $Name; ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName; keyKind = $keyKind }
Write-Verbose ("##[command]New-AzCosmosDBAccountKey {0}" -f (Format-Splat $parameters))
try {
    $null = New-AzCosmosDBAccountKey @parameters
}
catch
{
    Write-Output ("##vso[task.logissue type=warning;sourcepath={0};linenumber={1};columnnumber={2};]{3}" -f $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName, $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber, $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine, $_.Exception.Message -replace "`r`n", ". ")
}
```